# Двойное условие сортировки листа ( Comparator )

Tags: java, android

Имеется класс:

```
public class Man (){

    private int rating1;
    private int rating2;

    Man (int rating1, int rating2){
        this.rating1 = rating1;
        this.rating2 = rating2;
    }

    public int getRating1(){
        return rating1;
    }

    public int getRating2(){
        return rating2;
    }
}
```

Формируется `List` по rating2 (по убыванию):

```
public class MyComporatorByRating implements Comparator<Man> {

    @Override
    public int compare(man o1, man o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2.getRating1(), o1.getRating1());
    }

}
```

Что необходимо добавить в `MyComporatorByRating`, чтобы вначале списка были только те `Man`, у которых `rating2` от 1 до 5 в порядке возрастания.

Т.е. первыми в списке `List` были отсортированы `Man` по значению `rating2` от 1 до 5 (значения rating1 у них игнорируются), а потом все остальные `Man` по `rating1` от 100 до 0 (значение rating2 у них 0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Man {

        private int rating1;
        private int rating2;

        Man(int rating1, int rating2) {
            this.rating1 = rating1;
            this.rating2 = rating2;
        }

        public int getRating1() {
            return rating1;
        }

        public int getRating2() {
            return rating2;
        }

        public CompareWith getCompareWith() {
            if(rating2 >= 1 && rating2 <= 5) {
                return CompareWith.RATING2;
            }
            return CompareWith.RATING1;
        }

        public enum CompareWith {
            RATING1, RATING2
        }
    }
```

И компаратор:

```
public class MyComporatorByRating implements Comparator<Man> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Man o1, Man o2) {
            if(CompareWith.RATING2.equals(o1.getCompareWith()) && CompareWith.RATING2.equals(o2.getCompareWith())) {
                return o1.getRating2() - o2.getRating2();
            } else if(CompareWith.RATING2.equals(o1.getCompareWith())) {
                return 1;
            } else if(CompareWith.RATING2.equals(o2.getCompareWith())) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return o2.getRating1() - o1.getRating1();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Я даже не мог надеяться на столь полный и быстрый ответ!
Спасибо!

Comment: @Chekist Мне показалось, что это вопрос не из раздела "сделайте за меня", а действительно интересный вопрос... Мне лично не приходилось никогда сравнивать по двум, настолько разным критериям...

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public int compare(Coordinates o1, Coordinates o2) {
        int result = Integer.compare(o1.getX(), o2.getX());
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return Integer.compare(o1.getY(), o2.getY());

    }
```

примерно так. Этот компаратор сравнивает координаты в моём проекте. Сначала сравнивает ось Х, если Х одинаковы, то сравнивает по оси Y. Действуй по аналогии

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете Java 8+, то можете воспользоваться новыми возможностями: потоками и лямбдами. Ваш код будет гораздо проще:

```
Comparator<Man> comparator = Comparator.comparing(man -> man.rating2);
comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(man -> -man.rating1));

Stream<Man> manStream = men.stream().sorted(comparator);
List<Man> sortedMen = manStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Не нужно никаких отдельных классов и ручного сравнения.

Comment: В Android нельзя использовать Java 8

Comment: @metalurgus Ну, когда-нибудь можно же будет. Ответ с запасом на будущее. Да и вопрос к андроиду привязан только тегом (вообще-то тег следовало бы удалить).

Comment: @Atari,  нет, тег определенно удалять нестоит. Если бы не он, я бы этот вопрос не нашел бы.

Comment: @metalurgus Вам следует подписаться на тег "java". Подписываться на тег "android" и ожидать общие вопросы по языку — это неправильно. В вопросах с тегом "android" должно быть хоть что-то, что связывает их с этой платформой.

Comment: @Atari, а я собственно и не собирался искать общие вопросы по Java. Считаю, что тут есть толпа людей, способных ответить на общие вопросы по Java лучше меня... А вообще, следуя логике - правильно, этот вопрос можно было бы обобщить до Java...

Answer (score 0):

Из Вашего описания следует, что:

1. `rating2` є [0, 5],
2. `rating1` є [0, 100].

В этом случае, компаратор можно переписать без всякого добавления `enum`'ов в класс `Man`. Он будет таким:

```
public class MyComporatorByRating implements Comparator<Man>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Man o1, Man o2) {
        if(o1.getRating2() == 0 && o2.getRating2() == 0){
            return -Integer.compare(o1.getRating1(), o2.getRating1());
        }
        else if(o1.getRating2() == 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(o2.getRating2() == 0){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            return Integer.compare(o1.getRating2(), o2.getRating2());
        }
    }
}
```

Также замечу, что оба поля класса `Man` можно объявить как `final` (поскольку у Вас нет методов `set()`, то эти поля неизменяемы).