# Двойное условие сортировки массива (есть исходный код на Java !)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Есть массив:

```
someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

В нем лежат объекты с полями `zrating` и `rating`.

Как перебрать этот массив, чтобы вначале были объекты у которых `zrating = 1`, `zrating = 2`... `zrating = 5` (значение поля `rating` не учитывается), а уже только потом были объекты со значениями поля `rating` по убыванию?

[тут есть ответ на аналогичный вопрос, но только для Андроида](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413225/17111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем не подошла обычная сортировка? Для сохранения порядка из базы на элементах с `zrating` от 1 до 5 используем стабильную сортировку.

```
// вспомогательная функция
NSComparisonResult compareInts(int l, int r)
{
    return (l < r) ? NSOrderedAscending :
           (l > r) ? NSOrderedDescending :
                   NSOrderedSame;
}

[someArray sortWithOptions:NSSortStable usingComparator:
     ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
     {
         YourObject *o1 = (YourObject*)obj1;
         YourObject *o2 = (YourObject*)obj2;

         Bool o1HasZrating = (o1.zrating <= 5 && o1.zrating >= 1);
         Bool o2HasZrating = (o2.zrating <= 5 && o2.zrating >= 1);

         if (o1HasZrating && !o2HasZrating)
             return NSOrderedDescending;

         if (!o1HasZrating && o2HasZrating)
             return NSOrderedAscending;

         if (o1HasZrating && o2HasZrating)
             return compareInts(o1.zrating, o2.zrating);

         // тут у обоих объектов zrating вне промежутка 1..5
         return compareInts(o1.rating, o2.rating);
     }];
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ! 1) Принцип такой - массив заполняется из внешней БД, поэтому при одинаковом zrating у разных объектов, порядок должен оставаться как до сортировки. 2) "Плохой" zrating - что Вы имеете ввиду? Он либо от 1 до 5 (когда сортировка по этому полю zrating), либо от 6 до 8 (когда сортировка по полю rating, и zrating не учитывается в этом случае)

Comment: @Chekist: под «плохим» имеется в виду «не от 1 до 5»

Comment: @Chekist: Ну и снова исправил :)

Comment: А можно к существующим условиям сортировки добавить еще одно, когда рейтинг o.zrating == 8, то необходима сортировка по о1.zakazchikName (NSString) по алфавиту? Строка может состоять из нескольких слов, начинаться с латинской буквы или с цифры.

Comment: @Chekist: В принципе, без проблем, просто добавляете ещё одно условие.